# Using python to batch export geometry node generated objects

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

Using python to batch export geometry node generated objects.

I can export an object to an STL file using python with the script below:

**Script:**

```
import bpy
import os

# get the current path and make a new folder for the exported meshes
destination_path = '/tmp/0/stl'

# if path doesn't exist, create, else skip that step
if not os.path.exists(destination_path):
    os.makedirs(destination_path)

# gather names
names = [o.name for o in bpy.context.selected_objects]

# deselect all
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

# iterate over named objects
for name in names:

     # select the object
    obj = bpy.data.objects[name]
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    obj.select_set(True)
    

    # export object with its name as file name
    txt_dim_x = str(obj.dimensions.x)
    #print(type(txt_dim_x))
    stl_path = os.path.join(destination_path, name +'_xdim_' + txt_dim_x +'.stl')
    bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath=stl_path)
```

What I'm trying to do now is to adjust/loop the Geometry Nodes object (using given values) and export each change in it's values to an STL file.  **Basically, I'm trying to create multiple versions of a geometry nodes object using python and have them exported as STL files**.

**Example:**

I have an object in geometry nodes that it's x,y,z size/vertex groups can be adjusted using geometry nodes.
(**see red arrows**)

[image: img1]

**My thinking/logic was:**

1. Adjust each geometry nodes field (x,y,z) **0 to 3 in steps of 1.5 using python**
   (**I'm having trouble figuring out how to loop through each geometry node variable and export each individual one**)
2. Export each change to an STL file using the size/variable changes as part of the filename.
   (filename_x_0.0mm_y_0.0mm_z_0.0mm
   filename_x_1.5mm_y_0.0mm_z_0.0mm
   filename_x_1.5mm_y_1.5mm_z_0.0mm
   filename_x_1.5mm_y_1.5mm_z_1.5mm
   ....)

Attached file:

[image]